# Checking whether the intent is empty before consuming the result

Tags: android, android-intent

I am getting an intent from onPostExecute method in my onNewIntent method. Sometimes this intent has value and only then I want to display my Dialog window but currently AlertDialog is being displayed in the method even when the intent is empty? How can I avoid that since I am already checking for intent extra.

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null && extras.containsKey("stop_route")) {

        ArrayList<Integer> routeList = extras.getIntegerArrayList("stop_route");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
           .
           .
           .

    }
}
```

onPostExecute method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // Intent with Conetxt of the Asyntask class and
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("stop_route", routes);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: `boolean isValuePresent = extras.containsKey("stop_route")`

Comment: @Sebastian: I have changed it but it still the same problem. I think It was the same too before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try checking that : 
extras.getIntegerArrayList("stop_route").length > 0 when the result comes back in your if conditions.

Comment: Yes it works please can you explain me why my solution does not work? I though the intent is being checked like this whether it is empty or not .

Comment: I would guess that your onPostExecute method might just have put an empty list in the bundle when its gets nothing back.

Comment: and how can I avoid that int the onPostExecut method? I added the `onPostExecute` method to the question if you want take a look.

Comment: I don't think there is a great way, what you could do tho is , 

if(null != routes && routes.length > 0)
{
 intent.putIntegerArrayListExtra("stop_route", routes);
}

then when your check happens in onNewIntent extras.containsKey("stop_route") could be true of false.